# Profile id _SELF_ is not registered error while installing new plugin in eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-mars, eclipse-marketplace

I am trying to install plugin from Eclipse Marketplace, but while installing Spring core ide plugin I am getting Profile Id not registered error.

[image: screenshot]

I am using Eclipse Mars. I am using Windows 7 ultimate version.

Comment: It looks like your installation is broken (the p2 profile contains the description what you have installed). Consider [installing a fresh version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) instead using an outdated version. (You can install additional plug-ins from your old installation via _File > Import...: Install > From Existing Installation_.)

Comment: @howlger thanks for your reply but though I have installed fresh version and deleted .p2 folder,  its not working for me. Also I downloaded the new Eclipse i.e Oxygen.1 , its sowing same exception.

Comment: sorry @howlger but I deleted .p2 folder to resolve this issue. While surfing on internet for this issue, In one of the community for developers they told me to delete this .p2 folder. but after that also the problem is not resolved

Comment: You deleted the `.p2` folder in your home directory, not the `p2` folder in your home directory, right? Did you used the [Eclipse Installer or a package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)? If using the Eclipse Installer, by deleting the `.p2` folder in your home directory you have deleted all the substantial ones (plug-ins pool, profiles, etc.). Try to use an Eclipse IDE package (e. g. the [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen1a)) instead.

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse IDE package and I deleted .p2 folder from following path  -  C:\Users\gonkar\.p2

Comment: Did you also get an error with the Oxygen.1a package? If yes, please add the full error description and the stack trace of your error to your question and a link to the Eclipse Marketplace item.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=239753&goto=724923&#msg_724923 this solved my problem. Sorry for waking up zombie.

Comment: @OnkarG have you ever found solution to your problem? I have this issue also.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you self-host "launch as Eclipse application" are you sure that you have the p2 bundles selected?  This includes the p2 bundles, the needed ecf bundles, DS and the *equinox.util. DS must also be started.
2. In Eclipse 3.6 there is a checky (on the configuration tab in the launch configuration) that says "Support software installation in the launched application". Can you make sure this is checked?

[Refer this link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=316134)